# SQL Server 2017 Convert Varchar to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date stored as `nvarchar` which I cannot seem to convert to a date.

I have tried the following but get the error message

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
select cast([month-year] as date) from [Reporting].[AIM].[Hires_PBI]

select convert(date, [month-year], 103)from [Reporting].[AIM].[Hires_PBI]
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: So what's in `month-year`? We can't look into your DB. If it's something like `2019-01` or `201901` it's a simple matter of adding `-01` or `01` and using the appropriate style (112 or 23, respectively).

Comment: Please [edit] with column types, sample input data and desired results.

Comment: We need to see some sample data that is failing. However you can probably solve it yourself with `try_convert`.

Comment: yes good point month year is in the format Jun-21

Comment: Why do you think you can subtract a year from a month? What could that possibly do?

Comment: Y2K once again - how sad. Worse - you don't have a date at all. You have a month and 2 digit year. You will need to make an assumption to convert it to a date. So which day of the month do you want to assume in the conversion?

Comment: @RyanBrice so you want June 1, 1921? Or June 1, 2021? There's **no excuse** for using two-digit years. You can't just assume what century they refer to. Just 1 year ago Lloyd's, RBS and DVLA [crashed because they used a hack instead of fixing their Y2K code](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/) that assumed values above 20 referred to 1920.

Comment: @RyanBrice you can't even `yes but` this. This was the big IT news before COVID19. There are pension and insurance calculations that will fail no matter what cutoff date your system may be using. You code *will* mangle up hire dates in just a few years time, possibly causing incorrect benefit payments,  leave calculations etc. This isn't hypothetical. This already happened, 1 year ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the values that are causing the problem using `try_convert()`:

```
select [month-year] 
from [Reporting].[AIM].[Hires_PBI]
where try_convert(date, [month-year], 103) is null and
      [month-year] is not null;
```

Once you see what values are causing the problem, you can adjust the conversion logic to convert all values.  Or just use `try_convert()` to get `NULL` for the non-convertible values.